# Check if user is already logged in to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is there a method to skip the login class if user is already logged in with Facebook, and go directly to MainActivity?  I can't seem to find any solution to this in the Facebook SDK documentation.  I have added Login class, and SplashScreen class below.

Right now I only have the option to log out, and then log in again in the login class after started the app again.

Login class follows Facebook's guide, and i have removed all of my code to make it relevant in futre for readers here at StackO.

Login Class

```
public class Login extends Activity {

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");

 profileTracker=new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
         protected void onCurrentProfileChanged (
                Profile oldProfile,
                Profile currentProfile){
            Log.i("profileTracker", "profileTracker");
        }
    };
    if (profileTracker == null){
        Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    };


loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            System.out.print("Logged in");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.i("Error" , "Error");
        }


    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

SplashScreen class

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

private static final int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);

            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

-Hello You can use  `Profile Tracker` and start it in your `Onstart` method and check if `Profile` exist or not.

-Here is the sample **CODE:-**

-`profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(
                        Profile oldProfile,
                        Profile currentProfile) {
                    Log.i("accesstokensuccess", "gjk");
                }
            };
 profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
if(   (profile != null) )
{  ..you are already logged in..code for your main activity....}`

Comment: it dosn't work. I have updated my code.  I am not taken directly to the MainActivity when am already logged in.

Comment: @datasmurfen Please check it again.. or try clearing the app and logout and then again try this code

Comment: cleaned the project, rebuild, deleted the app from my phone, app from FB, and did a restart of my phone. Still no luck.